# Angular 2 ошибка при установке и настройке на Windows 7, как обновить

Tags: node.js, angular2

Как обновить angular/cli версии 1.0.1 в проекте до 1.4.3?
Проблемы начались еще на этапе установки и настройки angular на своей машине, и запуска сервера. На чистую *Windows 7 x64* установил *Nodejs v6.11.3-x64*, через *Node.js command prompt* выполнил команду:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

В итоге ошибка

```
Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os": "darwin", "arch": "any"}  (current: {"os": "win32", "arch": "x64"})
```

Установился *angular/cli 1.4.3* (проверил через команду `ng --version`)

Что делать с ошибкой, как повысить версию в проекте, и как потом запустить корректно сервер для проверки сайта?

Comment: Ничего не надо делать, это же не ошибка (error), а ворнинг (warning).
Ну или если очень сильно хочется что-то сделать, то перейдите с Windows на OS X.

Comment: @Yaant спасибо, буду знать. А как повысить версию у проекта?